# Attention OCR - implement on C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I trained my model and freeze graph use tools:freeze_graph of tensorflow, I try implement on window with this code:

```
Session* sess = (Session*)_session;
const tensorflow::Tensor t_input = get_tensor(img_data, wImg, hImg, byte_per_line);`

    std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;

    std::vector<std::pair<string, Tensor>> feed_dict = {
        { "input_layers:0", t_input },
    };

    const std::string nodeOutPut = "AttentionOcr_v1/predicted_chars";
    Status run_status = sess->Run(feed_dict, { nodeOutPut },
        {}, &outputs);
    if (!run_status.ok()) {
        return;
    }
```

`t_input` had shape: `[1, w, h, 3]`
but it returns :

```
run_status = {state_=0x0000000004958cb0 {code=INVALID_ARGUMENT (3) msg=<Error reading characters of string.> } }
```

, anyone can help me, thanks in advance

Comment: The cast on line 1 is already suspicious. If `sess` is in fact not a `Session*`, the error is not strange. And presumably the cast is there to shut up a compiler error message telling you that `session` is not actually a `Session*`.

Comment: thanks your reply, I check line 1 with another code and it's work fine, if had something i will update, thanks.